# Unity 3D movement issue when trying to move backwards

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-controls

My player controller works fine when moving forward, left and right. The camera always faces follows in the direction the player is moving/rotating which is great.

The problem is when I press down and try to move backwards. The camera shakes as though the player is trying to rotate 180 degrees but cant.

How can I allow the down arrow to move the player backwards smoothly?
Here's the script:

```
    private void Update()
    {
        HandleMovement();
        HandleGravityAndJump();
    }

    private void HandleMovement()
    {
        //capturing Input from Player
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")).normalized;
        if (movement.magnitude >= 0.1f)
        {
            //compute rotation
            float targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(movement.x, movement.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + player.eulerAngles.y;
            currentAngle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(currentAngle, targetAngle, ref currentAngleVelocity, rotationSmoothTime);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, currentAngle, 0);
            //move in direction of rotation
            Vector3 rotatedMovement = Quaternion.Euler(0, targetAngle, 0) * Vector3.forward;
            controller.Move(rotatedMovement * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
```